# I'm looking for docker-compose secret example with the option of copy .sql file to my container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

version: '3.7'

services:

db:

```
image: "mysql:5.7"

ports:

  - '3306:3306'

environment:

  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/my_secret

secrets:

  - my_secret
```

Now I want to copy a file to that container, something like the following:

docker exec -i bc568c22148f sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"/run/secrets/my_secret"' < init.sql

How to write the secret as a password?

Comment: In this case it might be the best to create your own Dockerfile, copy the `init.sql` file during the process and then use the Dockerfile inside `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Okay, but probably there's a solution for what I am looking for, right?

Comment: There probably is, I was trying to make your life easier and to point you in a direction where you could do it in less steps. If that's a hard requirement, to do it your way, then I'll let someone else post an answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks Marko